# Javascript how to create dynamic variable names for sim tree

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using Sim tree plugin to display tree structure, I want to set dynamic variable names.

`eg = var tree1, var tree2` etc.

[Sim tree plugin Git Hub](https://github.com/linjingming/sim-tree)

my js code

```
var trees = []
$.each(levels, function(id, value){
     var trees[id] = simTree({
     el: '#tree'+id,
     data: levels[id].sort(SortByName),
     check: true,
     linkParent: true,
     check: true,
     expand: 'expand',
     open: true,
    });
})

tree1.on('click', function (item) {
    console.log(item);
});
tree2.on('click', function (item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize trees to an array and push every `simTree` into the array.

```
var trees = []
$.each(levels, function(id, value){
     trees.push(simTree({
     el: '#tree'+id,
     data: levels[id].sort(SortByName),
     check: true,
     linkParent: true,
     check: true,
     expand: 'expand',
     open: true,
    }));
})

trees.forEach((tree) => {
    tree.on('click', function (item) {
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```